# Plot result of non analytical-integral

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have the following function:

```
h = 1;
c = 1;
k = 1;
B2 = (2*h*c^2)/(x^5 (Exp[(h*c)/(x*k*T)] - 1));
```

(someone can see that this integral is the Planck function). In the simplest case the function T is a constant.

But if I have that T is itself a function of a parameter: y, then the following integral could be solved only via numerical method:

```
T=y^(-3/4);
B1 = (2*h*c^2)/(x^5 (Exp[(h*c)/(x*k*y^(-3/4))] - 1));
Rslt=NIntegrate[2*Pi*y*B1,{y, 1, 10}]
```

But what I like to have is the result of the integral as a function to be plotted in terms of the variable x, as follow:

```
LogLogPlot[Rslt, {x, 1, 10}]
```

I do not understand if it is possible to do that or there is a problem in the definition of the integral or something else.

Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried defining _functions_? (See `SetDelayed[]`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
h = c = k = 1;

b1[x_, y_] := 2 h c^2/(x^5 (Exp[h c y^(3/4)/(x k)] - 1));
rslt[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[2 Pi y b1[x, y], {y, 1, 10}];
LogLogPlot[rslt[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

Edit: There seems to be an issue with `LogLogPlot` in V10.0.1 related to this and [Bob Hanlon's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) answer, which has been posted here: [LogLogPlot plugs in zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70239/loglogplot-plugs-in-zero).  Error messages are generated, but the correct plot is produced.  One can use [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quiet.html), if the messages are annoying.

Comment: +1 for doing it right, even though the Q is a combination of a borderline "easily found in the documentation" question and a duplicate of the [?NumericQ "pitfalls" answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! On a short calc like this I would probably do it as Bob did in his answer, but here I tried to show a safer approach to the OP. Anyway I'm quite sure it has been asked a zillion times before (and it will keep coming)

Comment: Strangely, I get "integrand has evaluated non-numerical values" errors with both Bob's code and yours in V10.0.1 but not in V9. Probably a bug, I guess.  Update: `rslt[x_ /; x != 0] := NIntegrate[2 Pi y b1[x, y], {y, 1, 10}]` fixes it.  `LogLogPlot` likes to plug in `x = 0`, for fun, I guess, since it's clearly a dumb thing to do in a log-log plot.

Comment: @MichaelE2 V9 Here.Impossible to check.  Please go ahead and add a note to the answer warning about that.

Answer (score 4):

```
h = 1; c = 1; k = 1;

B1 = (2*h*c^2)/(x^5 (Exp[(h*c)/(x*k*y^(-3/4))] - 1));
```

`Rslt` can only be evaluated for a numerical value of x so it shoud be defined as

```
Rslt[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[2*Pi*y*B1, {y, 1, 10}]

LogLogPlot[Rslt[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I get the same plot with `LogLogPlot[Rslt[100], {x, 1, 10}]`, but not with `LogLogPlot[Rslt[x0], {x0, 1, 10}]`.  The reasons for this are quite subtle and to hard to address here. In part, it's because `LogLogPlot` sets the value of `x` by using `Block` to temporarily set the global value of `x`, which bypasses the local parameter `x` in the definition of `Rslt`. Basically the local parameter of `x` is irrelevant, except that the pattern test prevents the evaluation of `NIntegrate` until `x` is assigned a numeric value through `Block`. See belisarius's answer for the correct way.

Comment: Bob, you might be interested in the comment and bug related to this problem I mentioned on belisarius's post.