# LogLogPlot plugs in zero

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

In testing the answers to [Plot result of non analytical-integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70196/plot-result-of-non-analytical-integral) in V10.0.1, I came across this behavior of `LogLogPlot`.  All three version give the correct plot, but the first two give error messages.

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, x];
k = 1/x;
kfn[x_?NumericQ] := 1/x;
f1[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[k*y, {y, 0, 1}];       (* kludgy *)
f2[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[kfn[x]*y, {y, 0, 1}];  (* correct way, but gives errors *)
f3[x_?Positive] := NIntegrate[k*y, {y, 0, 1}];       (* also correct and no errors *)

LogLogPlot[f1[x], {x, 1, 10}]
LogLogPlot[f2[x], {x, 1, 10}]
LogLogPlot[f3[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

The first two give the message (twice):

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand y/x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>

The second gives an additional message (twice):

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

Why does this happen? Is this a bug?

Notes: (1) It does not happen on V9.  I seem to recall this coming up before (years ago).  If folks have earlier versions, please test the code above.  (2) Reported to WRI.  (3) WRI confirmed it in 10.0.1 and stated it was resolved in 10.0.2.

Comment: Hints: The title. Try out `f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print[x]; NIntegrate[kfn[x]*y, {y, 0, 1}])`. (I dislike posting such questions, when I know the answer.  But as it relates to a question on the site, I also thought I ought to.  Feel free to answer first.)

Comment: I ran the code and got error messages from `f1` and `f3` but not `f2`.  I restarted the kernel and ran it again and got no messages at all.  Additional restarts also produced no messages.  Since I now cannot seem to reproduce the problem I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Which version(s) of *Mma*? I can reproduce it on a completely new session. (My system is a Mac, in case that makes a difference.)

Comment: With Mathematica 10.0.2 on a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.1, I get identical results (`Equal` and `SameQ`) for all three plots and no error messages.

Comment: No errors Mathematica 10.0.2 Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: 10.0.2 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in V10.0.1 is that `LogLogPlot` uses `x = 0` as a test point, instead of a value inside the specified plot domain.

The issue is resolved in V10.0.2.

Confirmed by WRI.

Comment: I guess I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer.  I wonder if resolved bugs Q&A should be closed.  Basically I don't like having unanswered questions...perhaps I'll pursue it on meta.